# Concentric Box colliders in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two concentric Box Colliders on same GameObject. Outer Box Collider rotates the object (on swiping the screen) and inner Box Collider plays animation when we touch the screen.

But when ray goes from my mobile screen to outer Collider it destroys and does not pass through that collider.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You could make the outer one a Trigger Collider by checking Is Trigger in the inspector:
[image]

and have the inner collider as just a collider. Then you can check the outer one with `OnTriggerEnter` and the inner one with `OnCollisionEnter`.

Alternatively you could give them different [Tags](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tags.html) and check for each Ray hit by checking for the tag (use `OnTriggerEnter` for this).

```
void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Inner Cube")
    {
        // We have hit the inner cube
    }
    else if (other.gameObject.tag == "Outer Cube")
    {
        // We have hit the outer cube
    }
}
```

Looking at what you want to do in your question though, using 2 concentric colliders is not as good as simply detecting which input action the user performs (tap or swipe) and acting according to that.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Physics.RayCastAll](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.RaycastAll.html). With RayCastAll your Ray won't return just the first collision but an array of all collisions.

```
RayCastHit[] hits;
Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
hits = Physics.RaycastAll(ray);

// If you have objects behind your object then sort the hit array by distance:
// hits = hits.OrderBy(l => l.distance).ToArray();

for(int i = 0; i < hits.Length; i++)
{
    RaycastHit hit = hits[i];
    // From here you can use a tag approach similar to what Flaming Zombie posted to check whether the collision object supports swipes or touches.
    // Once you find the first valid object then you can perform your action and break out of this loop.
}
```

However, there are a couple of things to note with this approach:

1. You will need to loop through each collision.
2. You will need to determine whether or not the user swiped or touched (you probably already have this down)
3. Colliders behind the GameObject will also return collisions.

If there is not a specific reason you are using two colliders then I would do what Flaming Zombie suggested and use a single collider. Here is a simple implementation:

Component on collider:

```
public class ExampleComponent : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void OnInteract(bool isSwipe)
    {
        if (isSwipe)
        {
            //Rotate
        }
        else
        {
            //Animate
        }
    }
}
```

Raycast logic:

```
RaycastHit hit;
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
{
    ExampleComponent c = hit.transform.GetComponent<ExampleComponent>()
    if(c != null)
    {
        c.OnInteract(isSwipe); // You'll need to implement isSwipe
    } 
}
```